# Wait Group Implementation

Tags: go

Can anybody show me by giving a simple example code how [Wait Group](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) works or can be implemented (better if it is given for example like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315970/mutual-exclusion-of-concurrent-go-routines))? Thanks.

Comment: The Wait Group link you provided has a simple example already. What are you asking?

Comment: I am asking for  Wait Group implementation for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315970/mutual-exclusion-of-concurrent-go-routines this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer of it i.e. on Mutual Exclusion of Concurrent Go Routine's. And code is on http://play.golang.org/p/bdBRtA6vS7. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think wait group (or sync-mutex) can be implemented for your example.

Answer (score 0):

It is implemented [like this](http://golang.org/src/pkg/sync/waitgroup.go). :)

Comment: Sorry Mostafa. Actually, I am asking for a simple program whose structure is like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315970/mutual-exclusion-of-concurrent-go-routines and implements Wait Group. As I am new in GO and has not so much resources, I want a simple code which implements http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315970/mutual-exclusion-of-concurrent-go-routines by using Wait Group.

Comment: Asking the same question twice in different forms is not the way to go here. Also, being more precise and clear helps in getting your answer. Here you asked how `WaitGroup` is implemented, but now it seems that's not what you want. Anyway, I go to your other question and try to help you there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler wait to see this is like a stack, you place an item on the stack, and then when a task is finished you pop it off. the WaitGroup will hold the code until the stack is empty. see the code below for an example that in its simplicity, should be able to help. it is designed to manage multi threaded behaviour that is a go function...

```
package main

import ("sync")

var (wg sync.WaitGroup )
func main() {
    wg.Add(1). //Push 1
    go func() {
        // Do some code here
        wg.Done() //pop 1
    }()
    wg.Add(1) //Push 1
    go func() {
        // Do some code here
        wg.Done() //pop 1
    }()
    wg.Add(1) //Push 1
    go func() {
        // Do some code here
        wg.Done() //Pop 1
    }()
    wg.Wait() // Until no more items to pop.
    //Do the rest of your code here.
}
```